# Using the function "IsNumeric" in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a question about using the `IsNumeric()` function in VB.NET.

I have to make a program that says if the value in a TextBox is numeric or not.

When I leave the `TextBox`, it has to display, in a `Label`, "your input is not numeric".

When I enter the `TextBox`, the text has to be deleted from the `TextBox`.

I have no idea how to begin with this :/

Where do I have to place the code if I use a Windows Forms application and only have a closing button?

I have tried about everything I know.

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is "numeric"

Comment: Geesh, no tryparse here?

Answer (score 2):

You want to setup your code in the "<strike>Leave</strike>Validating" event of your textbox.

In Visual Studio, select your textbox, go to its properties, in the events (lightning bolt), go to "<strike>Leave</strike>Validating", double-click it. This will bind the event and create a stub function. You want to use "IsNumeric" from there.

Comment: and how can id to this?

Comment: I would consider putting it in the `Validating` event instead.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Solid idea.

Answer (score 2):

you have three choices

depending on your need, i think validating would be one of the best one

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid text")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid text")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid text")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot :D it worked :D i would upvote if i had a 15 reputation :/

Comment: In the `Validating` event, you may want to set `e.Cancel = True` rather than setting the TextBox.Text to empty string.  Just a thought.  But for this particular scenario, I'm sure what you posted will work fine.